# WooCommerce: Send order details with an HTTP POST request

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an e-shop in Wordpress WooCommerce. I want to send the details of an order (when the order is placed) via an HTTP POST request (details susch as firstname, lastname, address etc.).

Basically I just want the php file that I must open to access the above variables when the order is placed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress has an event-driven architecture with hooks and filters.

There is a action `woocommerce_thankyou` you can use it to do something when an order is placed, will trigger after receiving order successfully. This hook will also pass your the `order_id` so you can get order details with it.

You can place the code inside your theme/child-theme's functions.php file or in your plugin.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_order_details' );
function send_order_details( $order_id ){
  // do something

}
```

Comment: Thanks! In which file can I add the above lines? And how can i access the variables that contain firstname, lastname, address etc?

Comment: using $order_id you can access the object with all the stuff.